# Designing an LC output filter for a DC-DC Boost high power system (2 MW)

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, boost, passive-networks, ripple

I am currently designing a dc-dc boost high power system. The input voltage is boosted from **1 kV** to  **1.2 kV**. The rated power is **2 MW** and the switching frequency is **2 kHz**. Due to the boost concept of operation, the output current shows strong ripples due to the switching mechanism. I have been advised to design a simple output filter to reduce the current ripples and also minimize the voltage ripples.

If I used only C output filter it will have no effect on the current ripple, that is why I am looking for any literature that might help me design an **LC output filter**, taking into consideration that my system is in the megawatt range.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, have you actually got hardware for this or is it a simulation?

Comment: This means either a multi(-multi)-phase, or IGBT/SCR/etc. In both cases, you shouldn't expect very high frequencies (so 2 kHz seems about right). I wonder how will you deal with EMI/EMC?

Comment: At only 1200 V, SiC could be an option, which could allow a much higher switching frequency. Did you consider this ? Since the inductors will be vast, any increase in switching frequency is welcome. Also what is the allowed output ripple ?

Comment: @Transistor It is just a simulation

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I will be using IGBT as my switch. I wonder how i will deal with them too. :D

Comment: @tobalt Thank you for the suggestion, I will definitely take SiC into consideration. I was thinking 5% of the output voltage so the max ripple peak to peak should be 0.05*1200 = 60V. I haven't made up my mind yet, any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: If you Google a bit about 1700V SiC MOSFETs you find that all things being equal you can increase f about 1 order of magnitude compared to IGBT. cree has 70A parts, so you would need only about 16 which you can arrange in 4 or 8 phases. One order of magnitude smaller LC will cut costs a lot, so before thinking about LC, I would reconsider the switch choice and go for SiC.

Comment: @tobalt thank you for the suggestion, I will consider SiC MOSFET as an option instead of IGBT. 
Would you have any literature though on the LC output filter design method, so that I can determine the LC values and prove theoretically that the LC option would be a costly option compared to changing switches?